# Android - ExpandableListActivity filtering

Tags: java, android, filtering, expandablelistview, textwatcher

I want to filter my expandable list through the edittext but I have no idea how to do it. I have checked few tutorials about TextWatcher in ExpandableListView, but I still don't know how to do it in ExpandableListActivity (yes, I'm beginner). Here is my code:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

private ArrayList<Parent> parents;
private EditText editSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    editSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSearch);


    getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(null);
    getExpandableListView().setDividerHeight(1);
    registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());

    //Creating static data in arraylist
    final ArrayList<Parent> dataList = putDataIntoArrays();

    // Adding ArrayList data to ExpandableListView values
    loadHosts(dataList);

    editSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

**loadHosts method in MainActivity:**

```
private void loadHosts(final ArrayList<Parent> newParents) {
    if (newParents == null)
        return;

    parents = newParents;

    // Check for ExpandableListAdapter object
    if (this.getExpandableListAdapter() == null) {
        //Create ExpandableListAdapter Object
        final ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter();

        // Set Adapter to ExpandableList Adapter
        this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        // Refresh ExpandableListView data
        ((ExpandableListAdapter) getExpandableListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I have also class ExpandableListAdapter that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter and method that puts data into expandable list. I know I should use onTextChanged method but how? I will be grateful for help.

**EDIT**

I have implemented Filterable to my ExpandableListAdapter class and added two methods:

```
    private class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements Filterable { 

        public void notifyDataSetInvalidated() {
        super.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new MyFilter();
            return filter;
        }
    }
```

Then I have created class MyFilter that extends Filter:

```
private class MyFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        constraint = editSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        ArrayList<Parent> oList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Parent> newList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {


            synchronized (this) {
                oList.addAll(filteredData);
            }
            for (Parent parent : oList) {
                if (parent.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                    newList.add(parent);
            }
            result.count = newList.size();
            result.values = newList;
        } else {
            oList.addAll(filteredData);
            synchronized (this) {
                result.count = oList.size();
                result.values = oList;
            }

        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        if (results.count > 0) {
            Log.d("TEST", results.count + " FOUND");
        } else Log.d("TEST", "NO RESULTS");

        ArrayList<Parent> filtered = (ArrayList<Parent>) results.values;

    }
}
```

where filteredData is a copy of original array with all Parent objects. I have also added this line in onTextChanged method:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            ((Filterable) getExpandableListAdapter()).getFilter().filter(s);

        }
```

Now I have to publish resulst through publishResults() method, but how can I do this? Logs shows, that everything works fine, but I don't know how to show this filtered data.

**EDIT 2**

Problem solved - just added these two lines to publishResults method:

```
 protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        parents = (ArrayList<Parent>) results.values;
        ((ExpandableListAdapter) getExpandableListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer so others with a similar issue can see it.